# Disable dictation from command line

Tags: command-line, defaults, voice-dictation

Is it possible to disable dictation from the command line, so that macOS never asks again if I want to enable it?

I know that many such things can be done using `defaults write` but couldn't find the right key for dictation. I'm using macOS Mojave 10.14.5.

Answer (score 7):

If you are talking about not having the *message box*, shown below, popping up again when pressing the e.g., <kbd>Fn</kbd> *key* twice, then use the following `defaults` *command* in  **Terminal**:

```
defaults write com.apple.HIToolbox AppleDictationAutoEnable -int 1
```

This changes the **Shortcut:** *setting* from e.g. **Press Fn (Function) Key Twice** *to* **Off** in **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Dictation**, and would be the same *setting* that gets set if clicking the **Don't Ask Again** *button.*

[image: Do you want toenable Dictation?]

Comment: The enum values may not be universal. On 10.15.7, it was "-int 0" that worked for me.